# unexpected bodies appear in ansys mechanical

Tags: ansys

I am using ANSYS Workbench 16.0, static structure analysis. An assembly is imported from NX 8.0.
In Design Modeler, I modified some parts and regrouped them, at last there are 129 bodies, and 9 parts are formed (one part contains all useless bodies and is suppressed). I renamed the bodies one by one (including suppressed ones). Everything looks fine.
But when I open Mechanical, I find one big body is missing, and many strange bodies appear randomly in 8 parts, which do not ever exist in Design Modeler. 
I have renamed every single body that exists, but the unexpected bodies have raw names. 
They are small parts, small faces or just empty objects with names like NX assembly and part names.
I've reset and refreshed the 'Model' step in static structure many times, but that doesn't help.
Please tell me how I can fix it?